# Cross compiling in Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, arm, clang, cross-compiling, macos-mojave

I am attempting to cross compile the following simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Hello World %d!\n", i);
  }
  do {
    i++;
  } while (1);
}
```

to an [nRF52840Dk](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-Tools/Development-Kits/nRF52840-DK) board with an Arm Cortex-M4 processor. My host machine is a Macbook Pro 15'' with MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 OS. I am hoping to run the program bare metal (without any OS) to start with.

When I run the following:

`clang --target=armv7-none-gnueabi foo.c` I get `foo.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found`.

Now I looked around a little and found this problem might be due to the different location of `/usr/include` in the newer OSX variants.

I have tried the following solutions without progressing any further:

1. `xcode-select --install`

Already done. I have xcode command line tools installed.

2. Run `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` and proceed with the installer

I am guessing this could be the possible error. When I run this, I encounter the installer, agree to the license, however I then get this warning `Installing this package may damage your system, and the installation may fail. To stop the program and the installation, click “Cancel Installation”.` When I continue anyway the installation fails every time. Could this have any relation to the fact that Mac has banned running 32 bit applications? How do people cross compile to ARM boards on the newer Macs then?

3. Set the `CPATH` environment variable to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include`

Attempted this as well but this leads to an explosion in warnings and errors. Although it seems like `stdio.h` is found, but it throws the following error:

```
error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
```

and a string of other errors.

So I am unsure how to proceed any further. Could someone enlighten me on this?